# Why does gcc -Wall give warning about zero-length format string?

Tags: c, gcc, string-formatting, printf, gcc-warning

I searched around a little bit for information on this but didn't find anything satisfactory.  Is there some special behavior to the function call

```
sprintf(someString, "");
```

that explains why this is warning (on gcc with -Wall)?  I only managed to find that the C standard allows zero-length format strings.

I tried the following example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[2] = {'a', 'a'};
    sprintf(str, "");
    printf("\'%c\'\'%c\'\n", str[0], str[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

which prints out

```
'''a'
```

which is exactly what I expected to see.
So, why the warning?

Comment: `sprintf(str, "%s", "");` won't make the compiler cry.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The fact that GCC issues a warning usually has nothing to do with whether the construct is legal C, but whether the GCC developers consider it either a likely indication that you meant something other than what you write, or just bad style. Here are some examples:

- `if (x = 0)` — you almost surely meant `if (x == 0)`.
- `printf(str)` — you almost surely meant either `fputs(str, stdout)` or `printf("%s", str)`; as written, the code is very dangerous.
- `if (foo == bar & MASK)` — you almost surely meant `if (foo == (bar & MASK))`.

etc.

In your case, I think GCC is questioning why you're calling `sprintf(String, "")` to do the equivalent of `String[0]=0;` (the latter is much shorter, faster, and clearer).

Comment: I agree that would be better, I just don't know if there is more reason than that for considering it a warning.  I'm certainly no authority but I didn't think that this particular offense to reasonable programming would have been considered warning-worthy

Comment: I agree, but GCC does a lot more annoying things with warnings. This is definitely a lesser offense. A bigger one is giving warnings on unused function arguments, which is *inevitable* whenever you're using function pointers that must conform to a particular signature.

Comment: Huh, I've never had that warning come up before, and I have had that situation come up

Comment: They might have fixed it. It used to happen all the time with gcc 2.x and 3.x and `-Wall`.

Comment: @R just don't name the function parameters and everything is fine: `int op(int a, int) { return -a; }`: no warning for unused second parameter.

Comment: @YSC: That's not C.

Comment: If they worry about efficiency they could just generate `String[0]=0;` instead of reporting doubtful warning. And also I consider `sprintf(String, "")` to be more clear since it better expresses an idea "make string empty" than `String[0]=0;` which just means "make the first byte of string zero".

Comment: While the warning is useful on literal `printf` and `sprintf` calls, it is unfortunate that the same warning applies to any user-defined function that uses the "looks like printf" attribute. Such user-defined functions can have other effects (e.g. printing a prefix, or terminating) which are useful even when the string is empty.

Answer (score 9):

You're getting the warning because gcc knows that the second argument to `sprintf()` should be a non-empty string, typically one with various format specifications — a functionally equivalent and "more legal" call to the one you're doing in your code would be `sprintf(str, "%s", "")`.  Also, there's almost always one to N additional arguments, enough to fulfill the format specifications.  As you're using it here, you're using it as a kind of `strcpy()`, which, while technically valid, is a very odd way to use the standard library.

Answer (score 4):

It's simply a warning by GCC. If you wish to suppress it for one part of your application, you can do the following:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-zero-length"
int main()
{
     // code that produces a warning
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wformat-zero-length"
```

Comment: I know I can get rid of it, I was wondering why it was there to begin with

Comment: I think it's just a nonsensical, harmful warning. It could definitely bite code where the format string is either zero length or nontrivial depending on a preprocessor macro's definition/value, and such code seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: It's _not_ harmful. It's just letting you know there's something questionable about your code, that you _might_ have made a mistake. Although `sprintf (str, "");` is legal, it's a rather round-about way of making _str_ a zero-length string, and could indicate a logical error in your code. It's not forbidden; just brought to your attention.

Comment: @Phil, it's harmful because false positives make identifying true positive warnings more difficult.  Most/all of -Wall is legitimate stuff you want to fix, so this hurts that.

Comment: This warning makes it hard to call an exposed `__attribute__((format(printf(...))))` library setter function to set an unexposed string buffer to the empty string in `-Werror` code (e.g. `User_details_set(&user, "");`.

Answer (score -1):

`-Wall` can be legally combined with `-Wno-format-zero-length`, it is very useful when there is need to pre-eliminate some `#define`'d string values, which are scattered all over the code.

> -Wformat

> Option -Wformat is equivalent to -Wformat=1, and -Wno-format is equivalent to -Wformat=0. Since -Wformat also checks for null format arguments for several functions, -Wformat also implies -Wnonnull.

> Some aspects of this level of format checking can be disabled by the options: -Wno-format-contains-nul, -Wno-format-extra-args, and -Wno-format-zero-length. -Wformat is enabled by -Wall.

[here is the source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)